# How to limit the text in numbers only from 0-59 in Edit Text in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an `Edit Text` in which the number can only between `0-59`, No other numbers will be typed  in that `Edit Text`, I tried `text-watcher` but did not get success. Any idea?

```
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494): java.lang.StackOverflowError
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:2765)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:10442)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:2765)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:10442)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:2765)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:10442)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:2765)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:10442)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:2765)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:10442)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:2765)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:10442)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:2765)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:10442)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:2765)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:10442)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.findViewShouldExist(View.java:4281)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.findUserSetNextFocus(View.java:4263)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:66)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:569)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:571)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:571)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:571)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:571)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:571)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:571)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:571)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:571)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:4221)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:5378)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:977)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:932)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2958)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2907)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:90)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2882)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at com.fishing.MyLocation$check_lat_degree.onTextChanged(MyLocation.java:236)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7226)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3045)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2907)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:90)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2882)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at com.fishing.MyLocation$check_lat_degree.onTextChanged(MyLocation.java:236)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7226)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3045)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2907)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:90)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2882)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at com.fishing.MyLocation$check_lat_degree.onTextChanged(MyLocation.java:236)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7226)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3045)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2907)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:90)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2882)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at com.fishing.MyLocation$check_lat_degree.onTextChanged(MyLocation.java:236)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7226)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3045)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2907)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:90)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2882)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at com.fishing.MyLocation$check_lat_degree.onTextChanged(MyLocation.java:236)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7226)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3045)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2907)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:90)
12-26 14:59:39.715: E/AndroidRuntime(19494):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.j
```

Comment: textwatcher alone can`t handle your scenario its Just Like "Precondtion "" On Condition" and "Post Condition" 
just you need to do is to make your own condtion and then attach it with the Textwatcher with any of the 3 methods

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this code in XML to allow numbers only in **Edit Text**:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text_id"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="numbers" />
```

To control the text values entered in that EditText:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        String strEnteredVal = edittext.getText().toString();

        if(!strEnteredVal.equals("")){
        int num=Integer.parseInt(strEnteredVal);
        if(num<60){
         edittext.setText(""+num);
        }else{
         edittext.setText("");
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks but it will aloow to input any number not between 0-59

Comment: But its giving stack overflow error? any idea? at line "edittext.setText(""+num);"

Comment: I have post plz check above.

Comment: This Error mainly arises due to complexity in the layouts: please follow the older post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737286/android-stackoverflow-error.

Comment: I know that this is a very old question but while googling for a problem I've in a project I've found this question. In my case your code is not working because the `editText.setText(value)` cause an infinite loop. I've fixed it by using a flag (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543449/how-to-use-the-textwatcher-class-in-android) @Yairopro 's answer). Also, the numbers are inserted in reverse order because when you set the text the cursor is moved at the beggining of the line and,in order to fix this,you need to store its position,set text and then move the cursor back to it.

Answer (score 21):

Here's how I like to do this:

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {
    private int min;
    private int max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        //noinspection EmptyCatchBlock
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.subSequence(0, dstart).toString() + source + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length()));
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Then set the filter on your EditText:

```
myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(0, 59)});
```

Comment: nice answer ..+1 from me

Comment: It's Not work for 111 ~ 999. how to change it to work with minimum biger that 11 ?

Comment: This code have a lot of bug. See solutions at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212518/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-min-and-max-value-for-edittext-in-android/60824434#60824434

Answer (score 2):

First Add input type as number and limit the number of input for editText.

```
editText.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2);
    editText.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

then

add a `TextWatcher` to check what user typing if the value is more than 59 show a alert or any message that number will be less than 60.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String added_number = editText.getText().toString();
    if (added_number.length != 0) {
        int number  = Integer.parseInt(added_number);

        if (number > 59)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, "Not more than 59", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void addAddTextChangeListener(final EditText et) {
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            boolean textModified = false;
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String strEnteredVal = et.getText().toString();
                if(!strEnteredVal.equals("") && !(strEnteredVal.length() < 2)) {
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(strEnteredVal);
                    if (!textModified) {
                        if (num > 60) {
                            et.setText("");
                        } else {
                            textModified = true;
                            et.setText("" + num);
                            et.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

and `android:inputType="number"` in `EditText` entry in xml-file.
But this code stops working once it gets correct input, so You should deactivate `EditText` after that.