# Stack overflow error in tab layout in Android

Tags: android, stack-overflow

I am facing stack overflow error. I am using this layout in 3 tabs, first 2 tabs are activities it not showing any error but for 3rd it shows error.

Third tab I used as a tab activity

Here is my logcat:

```
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302): java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.text.Styled.drawUniformRun(Styled.java:61)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:298)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.text.Styled.drawText(Styled.java:357)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:1387)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:370)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:365)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4050)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1365)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3046)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6846)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2257)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
10-03 10:42:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handl
```

here is my layout

1. ```
       <RatingBar
           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
           style="@style/foodRatingBar"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:visibility="invisible" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button2"
           style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
           android:layout_width="45dp"
           android:layout_height="35dp"
           android:background="@drawable/setting_btn" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/frame"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:text="Mary Smith"
       android:textColor="#585858"
       android:textSize="16dp"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
       android:text="asks:"
       android:textColor="#a6a6a6"
       android:textSize="15dp" />

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="20dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
       android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5" >
   </FrameLayout>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button8"
       style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
       android:layout_width="90dp"
       android:layout_height="25dp"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:background="@drawable/vote_btnimg" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/button5"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="55dp"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/frameLayout1"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
       android:background="@drawable/ask_question_box"
       android:gravity="top"
       android:hint="Add your comment here"
       android:imeOptions="actionDone"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
       android:maxLines="10"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:paddingTop="8dp"
       android:singleLine="false"
       android:textColor="#d5d5d5"
       android:textSize="12dp" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button3"
       style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
       android:visibility="visible"
       android:background="@drawable/report_btn" />

   <ToggleButton
       android:id="@+id/imageView3"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
       android:background="@drawable/follower_toggle"
       android:button="@null"
       android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
       android:textOff=""
       android:visibility="invisible"
       android:textOn="" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button4"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frameLayout1"
       android:background="@drawable/button_selecter_yes" />
   ```

   ```
       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/listview"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
           android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
           android:divider="@null"
           android:dividerHeight="0dp"
           android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp" >
       </ListView>
   </RelativeLayout> -->

   <!-- <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView4"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
       android:text="Rate this Question :"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:visibility="invisible"
       android:textSize="12dp" /> -->

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView3"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
       android:text="which shirt is sutable for me"
       android:textColor="#999999"
       android:textSize="15dp" />

   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/imageView7"
       style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button7"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5" />
   ```

   -->

   ```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button6"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="30dp"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
       android:background="@drawable/button_selecter_no" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button7"
       style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
       android:background="@drawable/skip" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView6"
       android:layout_width="40dp"
       android:layout_height="17dp"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:text="100%"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textSize="10dp"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView7"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:text="Enlarge"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textSize="13dp" />

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listview"
       android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:divider="@null"
       android:dividerHeight="0dp"
       android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp" >
   </ListView>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView5"
       android:layout_width="40dp"
       android:layout_height="17dp"
       android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
       android:text="100%"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textSize="10dp"
       android:textStyle="bold" />
   ```

Comment: if logcat is not clear,please see this log cat and do some need full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151898/stack-over-flow-error-in-android-text-styled

Comment: "Do some need full"?  Care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a cycle in views dependencies somewhere inside relative layout. I can see that `frameLayout1` view is dependent on `button5` and also this `button5` depends on `framelayout1`.

This creates a cycle which might be causing your problem because android tries to resolve and place views on screen and falls into this infinite loop of dependencies. Please double check this and preferebly use view creator for relative layout instead of typing it manually

Answer (score 0):

check your drawable images size.. 
the images size may have the reason of stack overflow. 
try to Use images of low sizes.....

Comment: All images are in kb only,that too less than 20 kb

Comment: Check this link..
It may help you.
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737286/android-stackoverflow-error)