# Android Stack overflow error?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, stack-overflow

In my application I got an error like this. http://pastie.org/8539020 Its indicates stack over flow exception. And also i have an another error in my tab like this http://pastie.org/8539027 . My application will be force closed. How can i resolve this? Can any body tell me thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the stack trace, don't link it.  Also, one question per post please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737286/android-stackoverflow-error

Answer (score 0):

Remove recursion from your draw method.

Answer (score 0):

For your second stack, this is a DB problem, you didn't close your database or cursor:

```
final SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

final Cursor cursor = db.query(
```

...

```
cursor.close();
db.close();
```